# How to implement DPP (wifi easy connect) with out of band credentials

Tags: android, wifi

I'm currently exploring the best way to implement DPP on an Android TV device so it can connect easily to a router without having to enter the wifi passphrase. I have the possibility to configure the router with informations related to my android device (mac adress, device public key) that are required to do the DPP auth.

There are some docs here that explain how to enable dpp on android : https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/wifi-easy-connect

But I'm still struggling to understand the following points :

- How to make sure that my device can be "discovered" with DPP by the gateway ?
- If I activate DPP like it is exlpained in the Android doc, which DPP flow will be used ? Do I just need to activate it and it should be discovered by the gateway ? It looks like there are several way of disocvering between the AP and the device : https://www.wi-fi.org/system/files/Wi-Fi_Easy_Connect_Specification_v3.0.pdf
  and the flow used by Android is still not clear to me

thanks in advance !

I went through Android documentation and Wifi Alliance documentation, also search for some examples but did not find any